# Making a jQuery scaled <div> stay at its new size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, scale, jquery-effects

I've got a circular `div` I'm trying to scale when a button is clicked:

```
<button id="2007">2007</button>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

I've got it styled with CSS for starters:

```
#test2 {
  background-color: red;
  opacity:0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
```

And my JS works to reduce the div size FROM THE MIDDLE CENTER, just as I'd like:

```
$("#2007").click(function(){
    $("#test2").effect("scale",{percent: 50},"1000");
});
```

Problem is, as soon as the scale effect is finished, the DIV reverts back to its original size and jumps to a new position.

Does anyone know how I can keep the DIV at its scaled-to dimensions AND prevent it from jumping to reposition?

[Here's a JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/ogicuj/6/edit) - just click the "2007" button to see what's happening.

**EDIT:** I've added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/JQdHf/)

Changing `.effect` to `.animate` doesn't work at all, and I'm sure there must be a way to use `.effect` without having the `div` jump, but I'm still stumped.

Comment: I have done exactly this before without any problems, but I didn't use `.effect()`.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of it?

Comment: Jodes, just added one above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI effect will restore it original property after complete, you can try using CSS or `.animate()`, here is a example of using CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/JQdHf/3/)

```
$("#2007").click(function(){
    $("#test2").css({
        'transition': 'all 1s',
        'transform': 'scale(0.5)',
    });
});
```

Updated: Have a see at this library (https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit), I think this is good for you request =)

Comment: thanks - the transit library looks really promising! I'll post an edit with what I find there...

Answer (score 2):

In order to make  stay in final state, after animation stops - you just need to use correct jquery version + correct jquery-ui version (I used jquery-1.7.2+jquery-ui-1.8.18 in this example - and it works): [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/snakeriot/K3Qn7/)

Source code:

```
    $("#big").click(function(){
     $(".target").effect( "size", 
      { to: {width: 200,height: 200} }, 1000 );
  });

  $("#small").click(function(){
     $(".target").effect( "size", 
      { to: {width: 100,height: 100} }, 1000 );
  });
```

As you ca see there is to specific stop functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try providing a `callback` to be executed after the effect is completed.

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/mULWX/1/

Comment: thanks for the tip - trouble with the callback is, it won't work if the position of the div is changed at all. I guess what I need to do is figure out a way to calculate the center middle point of the circle, then have jquery scale from there so the circle shrinks/expands in place and multiple instances of the circle can be placed on a page without having to type in precise pixel values for the positioning.